# ClassNotFoundException in isInstance

Tags: java, class, exception

```
class j {
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Object obj=new Object();
        String c ="Object";
        System.out.println(Class.forName(c).isInstance(obj));
    }
}
```

In the above code i'am trying to find whether obj is an instance of Object or not.I should get the answer as true but i'am getting an error.I am not able to figure out why the error is occurring.Can anyone please help me out?

```
error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or 
declared to be thrown
    System.out.println(Class.forName(c).isInstance(obj));
```

Comment: `Class.forName` throws the exception, you need to deal with it - Start by having a look at [the Exceptions trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would better answered using one of the many available tutorials, like [the Exception trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) and [Catching and handling Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) and reading the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)

Comment: yeah thank you but even though by using the try catch i'am not getting true and instead the catch block is executed.

Comment: `Object` is not a valid class name - It'd have to be `java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

1. the method **forName** throws an exception so you need to either catch them or rethrow it.
2. just doing `Class.forName("Object")` is not correct, you need to use the fully qualified name of the desired class (i.e with package included)

from the [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)

> **Parameters**: className - the fully qualified name of the desired class.

```
String c = "java.lang.Object";
System.out.println(Class.forName(c).isInstance(obj));
```

Comment: As returned by `obj.getClass().getName()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to surround the code within try catch or you have to make sure that main can throw excetpion:

```
try {
  System.out.println(Class.forName(c).isInstance(obj));
} catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
  // do something in case class can not be found
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException
```

You can not leave code, that is able to throw exceptions, without any safety net.

Make sure to use fully qualified name of class:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

or import it at the beginning of the source code:

```
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
```

Answer (score 1):

The method Class.forName declares that it throws the Exception *ClassNotFoundException* so in your code you either need to catch it or declare *throws ClassNotFoundException*  in the method declaration. Thus

```
Public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
```

or

```
try {
        System.out.println(Class.forName(c).isInstance(obj));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```